# get file extension from remote file for src.video

Tags: javascript, video.js

I would like to load a file from my storage (Azure) where i don't know the file extension from but i do know the filename, after i would like to use the right file for the src.video. Basically feed every optional video source into videoJS.

this works, but only for two predefined files (mp4/mov):

```
var video = document.getElementById('my-player')

fileExists()

function fileExists() {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('HEAD', 'https://linktovideo + '.mp4', true);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

function processRequest(e) {

    console.log(xhr.status)
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log("MP4 video)
        video.src = 'https://linktovideo' + '.mp4';

    } else {
        console.log("MOV video")
        video.src = 'https://linktovideo' + '.mov';
    }
  }
}
```

what i like to do is something as this, make a general search for the file (.*);

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('HEAD', 'https://linktovideo + '.*', true);
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
```

then from the actual file extract the extension and glue that to

```
video.src = 'https://linktovideo' + '.webm';
```

would something like this be possible? Now of course the XMLrequest returns 404
any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You don't really have an option to get all the files from the website directory as it's most likely blocked by the service configuration. Even if it wasn't I'm not sure there would be a way to list these files using browser's JS. The best option, in my opinion, would be to have a backend service on Azure that would check for the files on the server. Then you would make an API call to your backend service that would return you a list of files that are available.

Comment: i could of course always create a loop that goes over every option specified in an array or such and then make a request, until it returns 200 and proceed from there, however hoping for a better solution